# Pytorch What's the difference between define layer in __init__() and directly use in forward()?

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

What is the difference between the method that define layers in `__init__()` function, call layer in forward later and the method that directly use layer in `forward()` function ?
Should I define every layer in my compute graph in constructed function(eg. `__init__`) before I write my compute graph?
Could I direct define and use them in `forward()`?

Comment: See [this discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/understanding-net-class/2557)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Everything which contains weights which you want to be trained during the training process should be defined in your `__init__` method.

You don't need do define activation functions like `softmax`, `ReLU` or `sigmoid` in your `__init__`, you can just call them in `forward`.

Dropout layers for example also don't need to be defined in `__init__`, they can just be called in `forward` too. [However defining them in your `__init__` has the advantage that they can be switched off easier during evaluation *(by calling `eval()` on your model)*. You can see an example of both versions [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419474/using-dropout-in-pytorch-nn-dropout-vs-f-dropout/53452827#53452827).

Hope this is clear. Just ask if you have any further questions.

Comment: That means if a layer have train-able parameters, I should put it into `__init__` function? I noticed that softmax, relu and sigmoid don't have any train-able parameters, so I got this question.

Comment: Yes, you need to initialize everything with train-able parameters in your `__init__` - this is not the case for activations like softmax, relu or sigmoid.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps a lot.