# PyTorch Same Input Different Output (Not Random)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a model that I have trained, and I am testing it by running it (on `.eval()` mode).

Here are the exact lines and order that I've executed in debugger:

```
(Pdb) p feature
tensor([[[ -4.0563,  -3.8415,  -3.9542,  ..., -14.8424, -14.9201, -14.8960],
         [ -5.8481,  -2.0405,  -2.4438,  ..., -19.6938, -19.4901, -19.9180],
         [ -5.2424,  -1.2804,  -1.5109,  ..., -19.3892, -19.4397, -19.5012],
         ...,
         [ -6.4756,  -2.0376,  -2.0894,  ..., -20.0942, -19.9635, -19.8762],
         [ -6.5087,  -2.0452,  -1.9018,  ..., -19.7127, -19.8574, -20.0103],
         [ -7.0725,  -4.2817,  -3.3231,  ..., -16.7170, -16.9004, -17.0333]]])
(Pdb) p feature2
tensor([[[ -4.0563,  -3.8415,  -3.9542,  ..., -14.8424, -14.9201, -14.8960],
         [ -5.8481,  -2.0405,  -2.4438,  ..., -19.6938, -19.4901, -19.9180],
         [ -5.2424,  -1.2804,  -1.5109,  ..., -19.3892, -19.4397, -19.5012],
         ...,
         [ -6.4756,  -2.0376,  -2.0894,  ..., -20.0942, -19.9635, -19.8762],
         [ -6.5087,  -2.0452,  -1.9018,  ..., -19.7127, -19.8574, -20.0103],
         [ -7.0725,  -4.2817,  -3.3231,  ..., -16.7170, -16.9004, -17.0333]]])
(Pdb) torch.all(feature == feature2)
tensor(True)
(Pdb) prediction_tag, prediction_time = model(feature)
(Pdb) prediction_tag2, prediction_time2 = model(feature2)
(Pdb) prediction_time 
tensor([[[9.6584e-06, 3.9059e-05, 4.0984e-06,  ..., 1.7644e-04,
          1.0589e-02, 4.4167e-06],
         [9.6584e-06, 3.9059e-05, 4.0984e-06,  ..., 1.7644e-04,
          1.0589e-02, 4.4167e-06],
         [9.3993e-06, 3.7754e-05, 3.9786e-06,  ..., 1.7362e-04,
          1.0243e-02, 4.2382e-06],
         ...,
         [7.8885e-06, 1.1077e-05, 3.8594e-06,  ..., 1.9443e-04,
          3.8032e-03, 6.6878e-06],
         [8.0696e-06, 1.1217e-05, 3.9580e-06,  ..., 2.0004e-04,
          3.7598e-03, 6.8072e-06],
         [8.0696e-06, 1.1217e-05, 3.9580e-06,  ..., 2.0004e-04,
          3.7598e-03, 6.8072e-06]]])
(Pdb) p prediction_time2
tensor([[[8.0289e-07, 2.0557e-05, 2.5803e-05,  ..., 3.3225e-04,
          4.4547e-03, 8.4192e-06],
         [8.0289e-07, 2.0557e-05, 2.5803e-05,  ..., 3.3225e-04,
          4.4547e-03, 8.4192e-06],
         [7.6509e-07, 1.9805e-05, 2.4918e-05,  ..., 3.2385e-04,
          4.3618e-03, 7.9963e-06],
         ...,
         [7.3927e-07, 8.7688e-06, 1.8454e-05,  ..., 1.9831e-04,
          1.9305e-03, 6.2879e-06],
         [7.7376e-07, 8.8673e-06, 1.8517e-05,  ..., 2.0194e-04,
          1.8297e-03, 6.3183e-06],
         [7.7376e-07, 8.8673e-06, 1.8517e-05,  ..., 2.0194e-04,
          1.8297e-03, 6.3183e-06]]])
(Pdb) torch.all(prediction_time == prediction_time2)
tensor(False)
```

As you can see, even though `feature` and `feature2` are seemingly the same inputs, the outputs by the model do not match. This isn't random either, as after I have executed those lines above and running these lines below:

```
(Pdb) prediction_tag, prediction_time = model(feature)
(Pdb) prediction_time
tensor([[[9.6584e-06, 3.9059e-05, 4.0984e-06,  ..., 1.7644e-04,
          1.0589e-02, 4.4167e-06],
         [9.6584e-06, 3.9059e-05, 4.0984e-06,  ..., 1.7644e-04,
          1.0589e-02, 4.4167e-06],
         [9.3993e-06, 3.7754e-05, 3.9786e-06,  ..., 1.7362e-04,
          1.0243e-02, 4.2382e-06],
         ...,
         [7.8885e-06, 1.1077e-05, 3.8594e-06,  ..., 1.9443e-04,
          3.8032e-03, 6.6878e-06],
         [8.0696e-06, 1.1217e-05, 3.9580e-06,  ..., 2.0004e-04,
          3.7598e-03, 6.8072e-06],
         [8.0696e-06, 1.1217e-05, 3.9580e-06,  ..., 2.0004e-04,
          3.7598e-03, 6.8072e-06]]])
(Pdb) prediction_tag2, prediction_time2 = model(feature2)
(Pdb) prediction_time2
tensor([[[8.0289e-07, 2.0557e-05, 2.5803e-05,  ..., 3.3225e-04,
          4.4547e-03, 8.4192e-06],
         [8.0289e-07, 2.0557e-05, 2.5803e-05,  ..., 3.3225e-04,
          4.4547e-03, 8.4192e-06],
         [7.6509e-07, 1.9805e-05, 2.4918e-05,  ..., 3.2385e-04,
          4.3618e-03, 7.9963e-06],
         ...,
         [7.3927e-07, 8.7688e-06, 1.8454e-05,  ..., 1.9831e-04,
          1.9305e-03, 6.2879e-06],
         [7.7376e-07, 8.8673e-06, 1.8517e-05,  ..., 2.0194e-04,
          1.8297e-03, 6.3183e-06],
         [7.7376e-07, 8.8673e-06, 1.8517e-05,  ..., 2.0194e-04,
          1.8297e-03, 6.3183e-06]]])
```

I get the same, different outputs. Why am I experiencing this issue? I am totally confused.

Notes: I have checked that both `feature` and `feature2` have dtypes of `torch.float32`. `feature` was extracted from a torch DataLoader that was set up, while `feature2` was directly obtained from reading a file.

EDIT: Here is how the model was constructed:

```
class CRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputdim, outputdim, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        features = nn.ModuleList()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            Block2D(1, 32),
            nn.LPPool2d(4, (2, 4)),
            Block2D(32, 128),
            Block2D(128, 128),
            nn.LPPool2d(4, (2, 4)),
            Block2D(128, 128),
            Block2D(128, 128),
            nn.LPPool2d(4, (1, 4)),
            nn.Dropout(0.3),
        )
        with torch.no_grad():
            rnn_input_dim = self.features(torch.randn(1, 1, 500,
                                                      inputdim)).shape
            rnn_input_dim = rnn_input_dim[1] * rnn_input_dim[-1]

        self.gru = nn.GRU(rnn_input_dim,
                          128,
                          bidirectional=True,
                          batch_first=True)
        self.temp_pool = parse_poolingfunction(kwargs.get(
            'temppool', 'linear'),
                                               inputdim=256,
                                               outputdim=outputdim)
        self.outputlayer = nn.Linear(256, outputdim)
        self.features.apply(init_weights)
        self.outputlayer.apply(init_weights)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch, time, dim = x.shape
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)
        x = self.features(x)
        x = x.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().flatten(-2)
        x, _ = self.gru(x)
        decision_time = torch.sigmoid(self.outputlayer(x)).clamp(1e-7, 1.)
        decision_time = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(
            decision_time.transpose(1, 2),
            time,
            mode='linear',
            align_corners=False).transpose(1, 2)
        decision = self.temp_pool(x, decision_time).clamp(1e-7, 1.).squeeze(1)
        return decision, decision_time

def crnn(inputdim=64, outputdim=527, pretrained_file='gpv_f'):
    model = CRNN(inputdim, outputdim)
    if pretrained_file:
        state = torch.load(Path(__file__).parent / pretrained_file,
                           map_location='cpu')
        model.load_state_dict(state, strict=True)
    return model
```

with the following helpers:

```
class Block2D(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, cin, cout, kernel_size=3, padding=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.block = nn.Sequential(
            nn.BatchNorm2d(cin),
            nn.Conv2d(cin,
                      cout,
                      kernel_size=kernel_size,
                      padding=padding,
                      bias=False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True, negative_slope=0.1))

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.block(x)

def init_weights(m):
    if isinstance(m, (nn.Conv2d, nn.Conv1d)):
        nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight)
        if m.bias is not None:
            nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
    elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
        nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
        if m.bias is not None:
            nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
    if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
        nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(m.weight)
        if m.bias is not None:
            nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)


class LinearSoftPool(nn.Module):
    """LinearSoftPool

    Linear softmax, takes logits and returns a probability, near to the actual maximum value.
    Taken from the paper:

        A Comparison of Five Multiple Instance Learning Pooling Functions for Sound Event Detection with Weak Labeling
    https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.09050

    """
    def __init__(self, pooldim=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.pooldim = pooldim

    def forward(self, logits, time_decision):
        return (time_decision**2).sum(self.pooldim) / time_decision.sum(
            self.pooldim)


class MeanPool(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pooldim=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.pooldim = pooldim

    def forward(self, logits, decision):
        return torch.mean(decision, dim=self.pooldim)


def parse_poolingfunction(poolingfunction_name='mean', **kwargs):
    """parse_poolingfunction
    A heler function to parse any temporal pooling
    Pooling is done on dimension 1

    :param poolingfunction_name:
    :param **kwargs:
    """
    poolingfunction_name = poolingfunction_name.lower()
    if poolingfunction_name == 'mean':
        return MeanPool(pooldim=1)
    elif poolingfunction_name == 'linear':
        return LinearSoftPool(pooldim=1)
```

Comment: Is your problem similar to [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/same-input-same-weights-different-output/72476/3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53879727/pytorch-how-to-deactivate-dropout-in-evaluation-mode), i think we need to see your model structure too

Comment: This problem is surely underlaying your model.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without the model.
In general you sohuld always follow the [REPRODUCIBILITY](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) guidelines from pytorch so try to set `torch.manual_seed(0)` and `np.random.seed(0)` if you use numpy somewhere before every execution and set

```
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
```

in the beginning. See if this changes anything.