# Difference between nn.MaxPool2d vs.nn.functional.max_pool2d?

Tags: python, module, pytorch, forward

Whats the difference between: `nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size, stride)` and `nn.functional.max_pool2d(t, kernel_size, stride)`?

The first one I define in the module and the second in the forward function?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nn.Dropout vs. F.dropout pyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419474/nn-dropout-vs-f-dropout-pytorch)

Answer (score 8):

They are essentially the same. The difference is that `torch.nn.MaxPool2d` is an explicit `nn.Module` that calls through to `torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d()` it its own `forward()` method.

You can look at the source for `torch.nn.MaxPool2d` here and see the call for yourself: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/pooling.html#MaxPool2d

Reproduced below:

```
def forward(self, input):
        return F.max_pool2d(input, self.kernel_size, self.stride,
                            self.padding, self.dilation, self.ceil_mode,
                            self.return_indices)
```

Why have two approaches for the same task? I suppose it's to suit the coding style of the many people who might use PyTorch. Some prefer a stateful approach while others prefer a more functional approach.

For example having `torch.nn.MaxPool2d` means that we could very easily drop it into a `nn.Sequential` block.

```
model = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Conv2d(1,3,3),
          nn.ReLU(),
          nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))
        )
```

Comment: In Keras, it is now suggested to use Functional API rather than Sequential API. Does it hold for PyTorch as well?

Answer (score 0):

The results from `nn.functional.max_pool1D` and `nn.MaxPool1D` will be similar by value; though, the former output is of type `torch.nn.modules.pooling.MaxPool1d` while the latter output is of type `torch.Tensor`; this difference gives you different options as well; as a case in point, you can not call size/ shape on the output of the `nn.MaxPool1D` while you can call either of these functions on `nn.function.max_pool1D`.
I believe this should be similar in `maxpool2D` as well.